Hyper-V Server (Azure) IP Change
I'm having issues changing a server IP in Microsoft Azure Server. The system keeps giving me an error though I'm following the prompts. I have not been able to find much information on how to make the IP change - all info centres around changing the IPs of the virtual machines which is already something I know how to do. The O/S keeps rejecting the change, even though I sign in as the administrator and using Power Shell to make the change using the system menu.
The server has the Microsoft Azure O/S install (no graphics). Currently, the available adapter is set up as follows (I have masked out the IP address):
Available Network Adapters
Index# IP address Description
6 XX.XX.XXX.XX Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter
I need to change the IP address here. When I select the adapter 6 I get a listing of the old information that needs to change (IP and Gateway). The following are the options:
1 - Set Network Adapter Address
2 - Set DNS Servers
3 - Clear DNS Server Settings
4 - Return to Main Menu
I select 1 and fill out the new information then get the following error:
The IP address could not be changed. 70.
Any help would be gratefully accepted.

Just to confirm, this VM is NOT part of an auto scale or auto recovery. Those require DHCP.

No, not part of the VM, it is the Azure server itself
